# List management library in C for micro controllers

Tags: list, linked-list, microcontroller, 8051, sdcc

I am working on a project using a CC2532 which is based on an 8051 core.  I am using SDCC as the compiler.

I am needing to create a list of strings, and add, remove, append, list elements.

Are there any simple open-source/free libraries that are light enough to use in an MCU?

I found SimCList and SGLIB, but they seem overkill, I am wondering if someone knows of a simpler/lighter alternative.  I just need (add,remove,list,size) functions.  No need for it to be circular just a simple FIFO list.  I have a total of 4K RAM.  The number of list elements will be a max of 20.

Comment: If you need FIFO only wouldn't software stack be better? For ths you need only an array large enough for max. members and a stack pointer. For scalars (integers, floats, pointers) adding and removing is just `*--stackptr = x` and `x = *stackptr++`.

Comment: @Vovanium Jelipito wants a *queue* (FIFO) not a stack (LIFO).

Answer (score 1):

Simple lists are very straight forward to implement so you may be better served doing it yourself. If you want you can extract the files `include/proto/exec.h`, `include/exec/nodes.h`, `include/exec/lists.h`, `lib/NewList.c` and `lib/List.c` from [a library I wrote a long time ago](http://www.kim-minh.com/riffl/riffl-0.2.tar.gz) for a simple implementation. You can use `NewList` to initialize an empty FIFO, `AddTail` to add nodes to your FIFO, `RemHead` to remove nodes from your FIFO. The `size` function would look like:

```
unsigned int size(struct List *list)
{
    unsigned int res = 0;
    struct Node *node = list->lh_Head;
    while (node->ln_Succ != NULL) {
        res++;
        node = node->ln_Succ;
    }
    return res;
}
```

*Note* that the test for end of list is `node->ln_Succ != NULL` unlike many other list frameworks. This is in fact a redo of the [Amiga list system](http://amigadev.elowar.com/read/ADCD_2.1/Libraries_Manual_guide/node02D7.html).

Should I copy the all code for list handling here?

Comment: thanks, yes i'll give it a shot.  how you destroy/free an element ? i am not that familiar with it yet

Comment: The library does *not* do memory management. It means you still have to do the `malloc`/`free` dance yourself.